# Botkit is not sending Generic Template (Attachments) facebook messenger

Tags: facebook-messenger, botkit

I am trying to reply to the user with this message:

```
  bot.reply(message, {
                    "attachment":
                    {
                        "type": "template",
                        "payload": {
                            "template_type": "generic",
                            "sharable": true,
                            "elements": [
                                {
                                    "title": "MY title of bd",
                                    "image_url": "https://storage.googleapis.com/ssfkj.com/undefined",
                                    "subtitle": "undefined/undefinedundefinedn(undefined)",
                                    "default_action": { "type": "web_url", "url": "https://ssfkj.com/profile", "messenger_extensions": true, "webview_height_ratio": "tall", "fallback_url": "https://ssfkj.com/profile" }
                                    , "buttons": [{ "type": "payload", "payload": "DEL__PA_undefined", "title": "View more" }
                                    ]
                                }]
                        }
                    }
                });
```

But the bot is sending nothing. What is wrong in my code?

Comment: Can you share more of your code? Is this inside a controller.hears?
Turn on debug mode by passing `debug: true` in your controller config if you haven't already. Check the logs to see if there is an error sent back by fb when this code runs.

Comment: @aidonsnous have you figured this out? because I am still having this problem even with the latest botkit version.

Comment: @K48 set debug to true it will help you find the error for me it was the button type was set to payload instead of postback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My problem was on this level :

```
"buttons": [{ "type": "payload", "payload": "DEL__PA_undefined", "title": "View more" }]
```

The

> type property

should have the value

> postback

not

> payload